# Is there any way to truncate org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table item's text

Tags: java, swt

I'm using `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table`. I have a column whose width is 100, say if the corresponding `TableItem`'s text is longer than the column width, I want the remaining text to appear in a new line in that cell.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiline `TableItem`s as shown in [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/MultilineTablecell.htm) example:

[image]

**However**, you will have to handle the insertion of newlines (i.e. `\n`) yourself. `TableItem`s do **not** support [wrapping](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19496) by themselves.